# How to add precision from command line when generating rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I know how to do this from the migration file if I create it manually, but how do I add precision from the command line?

```
rails generate migration AddFoo foo_name:string dollar_amount:decimal {precision => 5}
```

something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do this from the command line - you'll have to edit the migration file and change the corresponding line.

Answer (score 0):

```
rails generate migration add_foo_and_dollar_amount_to_orders foo:string 'dollar_amount:decimal{10,2}'
```